# set params to web service using c#

Tags: c#, php

i can't set params to my web service
this is my code in php :

```
$myValue = $_POST['myValue'];
```

and this is my C# Code :

```
void POST(string url, string jsonContent)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";

    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes("myValue=" + jsonContent);

    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    request.ContentType = @"application/json";

    using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }
    long length = 0;
    try
    {
        //request.GetResponse();
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            length = response.ContentLength;
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                string WSReturned =  reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        //Nothing...
    }
}
```

i tested "&myValue=" and return null again

This is my PHP Code :

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['NewArray'])) {
    $NewArray = $_POST['NewArray'];
} else {
    $NewArray = "Not";
}

echo $NewArray;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you append `&myValue=Something`to your query string you don't use `$_POST` to get the value but use `$_GET`instead.

Now coming to your code it seems okay to me, maybe the error is an another point of your application.

I suggest you to check if there's a value in `$_POST`with [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), and then try to debug it.

If you get an exception then please post the logs, hope it helps :)

Comment: i use this : if (isset($_POST['myValue'])) {
     $myValue= $_POST['myValue'];
 } else {
     $myValue= "Not";
 } and return Not :(

Comment: Try using $_GET if you `"&myValue="` otherwhise do you get any error? Any exception while posting the request?

Comment: no , not any error or exception , only run my code and reader.ReadToEnd(); return nothing in my php result

Comment: just isset($_POST['myValue']) is false

Comment: Well it's hard to say anything without more details, have you tried to check if actually `jsonContent` has value?

Comment: 100% - have value